# Convert spaced-separated integers (not a string) into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6, integer

**FINAL EDIT: Mods, please close this question as it was a misunderstanding. My online code challenge instructions clearly stated that my second input would be space-separated integers and not an array or a string, so that's what I assumed I was getting. With further console logging, and a few slaps to the face since it's a late night, I realized that my second input ***is*** in fact a comma separated array despite what the instructions said (also noting that you can't pass space-separated integers as a single parameter to a function in JavaScript). Due to this misunderstanding, this question is now pointless.**

I couldn't find this on Stack Overflow. I've got two inputs. The first input, `n`, is an integer representing the number of integers in my second input. My second input is `n` number of spaced integers that I need to convert to an array on the spaces.

The first input looks like:

```
6
```

The second input looks like (note that this is NOT a string):

```
10 20 30 40 50 6
```

And my output needs to be:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
```

What's the most elegant way to do this in `JavaScript`? Also, is it best practice to first convert the spaced integers into a string?

Comment: "*convert the spaced integers into a string*" That has to be a string. There's no such thing called "spaced integers" in JavaScript

Comment: how exactly are you getting these inputs?

Comment: Update: turns out my second input is actually a comma separated array, contrary to what the instructions said. I'm voting to close this as this question is now pointless. Thanks for all of your contributions!

Answer (score 2):

You could `split` then `map` with `Number` constructor

```js
const str = '10 20 30 40 50 60'

const res = str.split(' ').map(Number)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can split it.

example:

```
const numbers = '10 20 30 40 50 60';
numbers.split(' ');
```

output:

["10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60"]